# Sublime Text проблемма с анакондой

Tags: python, anaconda

Вот эта ошибка выскакивает, при открытии python файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папка анаконды совпадает с папкой в ошибке (где Python37-32)?

Comment: @gil9red Да совпадает